# Google Colaboratory を動かすと「Google Driveがタイムアウトします」のメッセージが頻発に発生します。

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratory を動かすと「Google Driveがタイムアウトします」のメッセージが頻発に発生します。

Google Colaboratoryのチュートリアルを読み、MyDrive直下の複数のフォルダをサブフォルダとして移動させましたが、状況は良くなりません。対処法につきご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

Google Colabratoryの90分制限のことであれば以下の記事の方法などで対処可能だと思います。
[Google Colaboratoryの90分セッション切れ対策【自動接続】](https://qiita.com/enmaru/items/2770df602dd7778d4ce6)

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは

質問の情報が足りないと思いますが（頻繁はどのぐらいの頻度？使用しているブラウザ？）、まず考えていることを書きます。

もし頻度が高い場合、ブラウザが問題の可能性は高いと思います、できればChromeの最新バージョンでやってみてください。ブラウザのプラグインが頻繁にブラウザのクッキーやキャッシュなどを勝手に消したりする可能性があります、そのへんも確認してみてください。

注意：ブラウザをバックグラウンドにほったらかしままにするとすぐにタイムアウトされます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
自動更新を有効にして、Chromeの最新バージョンになっているので様子を見ます。

Comment: ちなみにもし自分のipアドレスが頻繁に変動する場合も落ち可能性が高いと考えられます。